# Multiline Regex XML replacement in Bash script (likely via Perl)

Tags: regex, bash, perl, multiline

I have an XML file with the following format.

I want to leverage the step name, which contains the characters "VM" on VM related steps. When I see "VM" in the step name, I want to replace the computer name filed with "VMname" and the computer id field with "VMid."

I want

```
<step sequence="106" name="Patch%20Baseline">
   <!-- No parameters accepted for baseline steps -->
   <target-set>
    <computer name="nameAndIDTarget" id="123" />
  </target-set>
 </step>
 <step sequence="110" name="Warning%3A%20Outdated%20VMware%20Tools%20Version">
  <target-set>
    <computer name="nameAndIDTarget" id="123" />
  </target-set>
 </step>
```

to become

```
<step sequence="106" name="Patch%20Baseline">
  <!-- No parameters accepted for baseline steps -->
  <target-set>
    <computer name="nameAndIDTarget" id="123" />
  </target-set>
</step>
<step sequence="110" name="Warning%3A%20Outdated%20VMware%20Tools%20Version">
  <target-set>
    <computer name="VMname" id="VMid" />
  </target-set>
</step>
```

This function will be part of a bash script, so if done via Perl I would prefer an one-liner or inline method. I am Perl/Regex stupid and cannot make sense of examples I have seen thus far.

Comment: Please show the code that you're having problems with

Comment: @shellter The OP's description and the sample output look fine to me. I only see one `step` tag where the `name` attribute contains the text "VM", and in the sample output, that is the only tag where the `name` and `id` attributes of the corresponding `computer` tag are updated.

Comment: Why use a regex at all? A syntax-aware tool such as XMLStarlet would make the update a trivial oneliner, and with far fewer bugs (a regex doesn't understand XML namespaces, doesn't understand CDATA sections, doesn't understand XML's escaping rules, etc).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot : Yep, you're right, I didn't look at that name attribute closely enough. Good luck to all!

Comment: @a-1, ...btw, are your systems guaranteed to have Python installed? If so, what's the minimum version? (Python has shipped with proper XML libraries out-of-the-box for ages, though 2.5 and newer have easier-to-use libraries in addition to the old-style ones).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here you go

```
perl -pe 'if (m!<step .*name=".*VM!..m!</step>!){ if (m!<computer!){s/name=".*?"/name="VMname"/;s/id=".*?"/id="VMid"/} }' test.xml
```

Leaving reference in case someone who doing voting doesn't know the Perl magic

perldoc flip-flop

Comment: @a-1, I can't speak definitively to the downvote, but there's a large "never use regexes to parse XML" contingent here on SO. For good reason; regexes are only even theoretically capable of working with regular languages, and XML isn't one. [Now, PCREs support capabilities that formal regular expressions don't have, so building a Perl implementation that's entirely robust and correct isn't easy to *prove* as impossible, but that doesn't mean that it's easy either].

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I guess some people just simply can not read perl or hate perl

Comment: @Boying, I interpret it as more to do with pedantry (around correctness in parsers) than dislike for perl. For an example of something your code gets wrong: A correct XML parser would consider anything inside `<!CDATA[` to be a literal string, not markup, and so would avoid running these replacements inside of them. Same thing applies to comments. Similarly, a real XML parser would know that if a parent element had a `xmlns="http://example.com"` attribute, that would mean that these were `{http://example.com}computer` elements -- not `computer` -- so `computer` rules wouldn't apply.

Comment: @Boying, ...btw, shouldn't it also be `<step [^>]*name="[^"]*VM`, to prevent a `VM` inside a different element or attribute on the same line from matching?

Comment: @Boying, ...you could write an answer in Perl using a proper XML library, and that'd certainly have my +1. Though it wouldn't be as helpful to the OP if that XML library didn't ship with the interpreter (as Python, for instance, *does* have native XML libraries that ship with the interpreter and thus will be installed anywhere the language is).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The requirement is oneline Perl. And by reading the original question, I can feel the it's just a one time job, you shall not waste time to write code for others, and Perls solgon, there is more than one way to do it, if some one don't like it. they shall give a new answer instead to downvote it

Comment: Sure (though "probably" perl was specified, so no, that wasn't a hard part of the spec). But, yeah, write-my-own-answer was how I went myself.

Comment: ...that said, may be a one-time job, may not; could be the input file is output from an automated tool and the processing needs to be invoked after every run. As for "wasting time", the goal here is to teach people how to fish, not to hand out fish, and if one is going to teach people things by example, I think there's a lot to be said for teaching them to do things the Right Way.

Comment: Well, this is a vaild solution(with restrictions), maybe working very well in his working enviroment. Maybe he's production enviroment has no internet access and could not install XML::Simple or other power full tools...
What I will do in future is to add Disclaimer, and it's who asking question do decide use or not.

Comment: @Boying strolling down memory lane and your solution is still running in "production" (for operational/administrative automation tasks) til this day. :)

Comment: @a-1 Haha, Thanks for sharing this info. Glad to know the old Perl is still useful somewhere in the year 2022 :)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't answer the question *as asked*, but the Right Way to do this is with XML-aware tooling such as [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/):

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '//step[contains(@name, "VM")]/target-set/computer/@name' -v VMname \
              -u '//step[contains(@name, "VM")]/target-set/computer/@id' -v VMid \
  <in.xml >out.xml
```

Note that this assumes use of the default namespace; if somewhere higher up in your hierarchy there's a `xmlns="..."` attribute, the question should be edited to include that.

Comment: That you for that, and you're correct that is the "best practice" method. Mainly was working off the fact that we have Perl on all of our systems but some other tool (such as xmlstartlet) may not always be available. However, upvote for referencing a cool tool!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution - to my mind this is too complicated for a one-liner.  It is very easy just to call a perl script.

```
$vm = ;                                         # $vm is set to 1 only if s step sequence with `VM` in is detected
while(<>) {                                     # Loop through the file, line by line
    if(m!<step sequence=.* name="(.*VM.*)">!) { # Check for sequence name containing VM
        $vm = 1;
     }
     if($vm == 1 && m!<computer name!) {        # Output special VM name   
         print qq!    <computer name="VMname" id="VMid" />\n!;
         $vm = 0;                               # Reset the VM flag
     } else {
         print $_;                              # Otherwise print the input line
     }
}
```

Comment: Quite fragile; change the output formatting to put anything else on the line with the `computer` element, and suddenly this is corrupting the file. Or if you have a `step` line that has a name matching `VM` but no `computer`s in it, you'd still have the `vm=1` flag set even after that step exits. And if you had multiple computers inside a target set, only the first one would be modified. And if you had any attributes other than `name` or `id` in the computer, this would be throwing them away without an explicit specification to that effect (if it still matched the regex at all).